# how to create object of static inner class in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
class LinkedList
{
    Node head; // head of list

    /* Linked list Node. This inner class is made static so that
    main() can access it */
    static class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d) { data = d; next = null; } // Constructor
    }

    /* method to create a simple linked list with 3 nodes*/
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /* Start with the empty list. */
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

        LinkedList.Node first = new LinkedList.Node(1);
```

> error --- cannot create instance of the static class  LinkedList.Node

The Question is, how can i create an object of static inner class in c#?

Comment: You cannot instantiate a static class. What is the reason you need it to be static? Can't tell from the code provided. Edit: just saw the comment... and it is wrong. Static is not needed for `main` to access the class.

Comment: You've included comment to the code: "*This inner class is made static so that main() can access it*". In reality, this class can be non-static and it still will be accessible from `main` method.

Comment: Java examples wont work in C#.

Comment: got confused because it was working fine java !!

Comment: also tell me how to instantiate it , it's not getting instantiated even after removing keyword static.

Answer (score 1):

You do not. A static class can only have static methods and can NOT be instantiated.

Comment: class LinkedList
{
 Node head; // head of list

 /* Linked list Node. This inner class is made static so that
 main() can access it */
 static class Node {
  int data;
  Node next;
  Node(int d) { data = d; next=null; } // Constructor
 }

 /* method to create a simple linked list with 3 nodes*/
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  /* Start with the empty list. */
  LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

  llist.head = new Node(1);
  Node second = new Node(2);
  Node third = new Node(3);
this a java code and they have initiated static class Node , which is working fine .

Comment: @Anish Did it ever occur to you that Java is not C#? That while the syntax may be similar at times, the meaning of keywords may not. Copy/Pasting Java code to C# and then complaining about changed meanings makes you NOT look smart. In particular, in C#, you do NOT make an inner class static to access it's properties. And "static" has a very specific meaning in C#. Time to sit down and program in C#, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line:

```
static class Node
```

to:

```
class Node
```

Static classes cannot be instantiated (in other words - you cannot use new keyword with static class)

Answer (score -1):

Nested classes are private by default. Hence you need to make it `public` instead of `static`.

Please read about [nested types on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx)

Something like this:

```
class LinkedList
{
    public class Node
    {
        ...
        public Node(int d)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```